# why an instance can't inherit property from class?

Tags: python, class

my code is like this below:

```
class Ball(object):
    pass
ball = Ball()
dir(ball) == dir(Ball) # True
Ball.__name__ # Ball
ball.__name__ # error
```

why doesn't `ball` have `__name__` from `Ball`?

Comment: Class instances do not have a `__name__` attribute. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` is something that's automatically available on classes but not objects. [Custom classes have a](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

> Special attributes: [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) is the class name…

while class instances don't:

> Special attributes: [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) is the attribute dictionary; `__class__` is the instance’s class.

Try

```py
ball.__class__.__name__
```

Answer (score 0):

When you access Ball it accesses the attributes in .**class**, to access the name from an instance of the class, you have to use the class operator, so ball.**class**.**name**

```
In [591]: dir(Ball.__class__)                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[591]: 
['__abstractmethods__',
 '__base__',
 '__bases__',
 '__basicsize__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dictoffset__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__flags__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__instancecheck__',
 '__itemsize__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__mro__',
 '__name__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__prepare__',
 '__qualname__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasscheck__',
 '__subclasses__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__text_signature__',
 '__weakrefoffset__',
 'mro']
```